# Can we find that who deleted a record in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working on CRM 2011. We have a custom entity "Orders". One of the order is deleted by someone (user). Can we find that who (user) deleted that record?

**EDIT**:

**1-** Well, as i mentioned that we have a Customized entity; it means that software development is involved.

**2-** This question is equal to "**Can we find that who deleted a record in SQL Server**"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have enabled auditing on your CRM and also on your entity "Orders", you can see audits in Settings -> Auditing -> Audit Summary View.
All logs are in [dbo].[AuditBase] table in DB. For deleted record Action and Operation fields are set to 0.

If audit is not enabled, I'm not sure how you can find that. Maybe you can search log files if your trace is enabled.

Comment: Thanks. let me check it.